# AndroidManifest.xml collided. Implementing Sinch library 3.17.1.aar

Tags: android, android-library, aar, sinch, android-sinch-api

Directly after creating a new project, I implemented the lib (sinch-android-rtc-3.17.1.aar) following theses instructions from the "how to" section : https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice-android-first-time-setup

[image]

When I try to build the project I have the following error : "Entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided"

[image]

I tried to implement an other aar file I found on Github from a previous version and everything worked fine.

Any suggestions to fix this in order to install the last version ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `android.useNewApkCreator=false` in your gradle.properties to fix this issue